# Problem when click to HTML links inside a ListView?

Tags: android

i used the code below for my listview and textview .

Code:

```
textcontent.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.get_text()));
textcontent.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

XML:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtview"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="put your link here"/>
```

the link looks like url and i can click it but it generate this exception

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:
>   Calling startActivity() from outside
>   of an Activity context requires the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.

any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: i have the List adapter in other class than the main Activity class and then i create object from the list adapter class from the main activity class and pass to it the context is that maybe the cause of the problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't pass application context to ListAdapter constructor. Pass your main activity instead.

```
ListAdapter flareAdapter = new ListAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(activity), Items);
```

Even if you create adapter in some other class you should pass main activity reference anyway.

Comment: thanks for the hint , this is what i did and it works
Context aContext ;
aContext = this;
ListAdapter flareAdapter = new ListAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(aContext), Items);

Comment: Thank you so much. I just pass the Activity as context to the adapter. new ListAdapter(this,etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the click caused that exception not something you want to launch?

As I see you need to add the flags to the intent (not sure what is your intent though)

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: If so, maybe give us more from the Exception log, let's see the stack trace.

Comment: i have the List adapter in other class than the main Activity class and then i create object from the list adapter class from the main activity class and pass to it the context is that maybe the cause of the problem ?

Comment: ListAdapter flareAdapter = new ListAdapter(LayoutInflater
     .from(getApplicationContext()), Items);